# uniform continuity of a function in ultrametric spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, p-adic-analysis

1. Consider $[0,1]$ with the metric $d_1(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
   0&x=y,\\
   \max\{x,y\}&x\ne y.
   \end{array}\right.$. Moreover let $(M,d_2)$ be an ultrametric space. Let 
   $f:(M,d_2)\to([0,1],d_1)$ be a function such that:

   - there is $a\in M$ such that $f(a)>0$,
   - for all $a\in M$, $f(a)<1$,
   - $\sup_{a\in M}f(a)=1$.

   The question is that: Is it possible for $f$ to be a uniformly continuous function?
2. If the answer of (1) is positive let $I=\omega_1+1$ and $\{g_i:(M,d_2)\to([0,1],d_1)\}_{i\in I}$ be a sequence of functions such that 
   for all $a\in M$ and $i\in I$, $g_i(a)>f(a)$ and for all $a\in M$ and $i>j$, $g_i(a)>g_j(a)$. Is it possible that for each $i\in I$, $g_i$ be a uniformly continuous function?

Comment: The answer to your first question is trivially yes: Take $M=[0,1)$ and $d_2=d_1|_{M\times M}$ and $f(x)=x$. Or did I miss something?

Comment: $f(0)=0$. However, you may do it!